# How does Flink countWindow work in detail

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm learning Flink with simple toy examples.

I have adapted the `WindowWordCount` example from [here](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-examples/flink-examples-streaming/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/examples/windowing/WindowWordCount.java) and run it on this simple data file

```
cat data.txt
a a b c c
```

I ignored the `slideSize` and only do `countWindow(windowSize)` (hence it's called tumbling window according to [this post](https://flink.apache.org/news/2015/12/04/Introducing-windows.html) for multiple window sizes. I'm confused by the results.

When `windowSize = 1`, the output is

```
(a,1)
(a,1)
(b,1)
(c,1)
(c,1)
```

which makes total sense. But when `windowSize = 2`, the output is

```
(a,2)
(c,2)
```

where is count for `b`?

when `windowSize = 3`, the output is empty, which I don't understand either.

Can anyone help me understand how the outputs are produced in the cases of `windowSize = 2` and `windowSize = 3`, please?

My code is on https://gist.github.com/zyxue/bc566180d2b01f1e2e77c1bbe3a7c5e5

And I run it with command like

```
./bin/flink run /path/to/target/myflinkapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --input data.txt  --output /tmp/out --window 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Trigger` for `CountWindow` only triggers the window function for complete windows -- in other words, after processing `windowSize` events for a given key, then the window will fire.

For example, with `windowSize = 2`, only for `a` and `c` are there enough events. Since there is only one `b`, the job ends with a partially filled window for `b`.

You can use a custom trigger that also reacts to a timeout if you want to generate reports for partial count windows.